# Checking for values in table (phpmyadmin, php, mysql), only returns a 0

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a page that looks if the text you enter exists in the table in my database. But it's only returning a 0, even if it exists.

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect("database", "user", "password") or die("Could not connect to MySQL. ".MySQL_error());
    mysql_select_db("myData",$db);
?>
<form method = "POST" action = "website.php">
<input type = "text" name = "text">
<input type = "submit" name = "button1" value = "check">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["button1"])) {
        $txt = $_POST['text'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM myText WHERE text = $txt");
        $quantity = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        echo $quantity['total'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: use quotes at `WHERE text = $txt` it would be `WHERE text = '$txt'` also `mysql` is deprecated instead use `mysqli or pdo`

Comment: Even better than @Saty's suggestion; forget the MySQL extension completely (PHP has now in version 7); switch to MySQLi or PDO and learn to use prepared statements with bind variables..... better to learn the right way of doing database queries right from the start of your learning, than learn the wrong way, and have to totally relearn it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");
?>
<form method = "POST" action = "website.php">
    <input type = "text" name = "text">
    <input type = "submit" name = "button1" value = "check">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["button1"])) {
        $txt = $_POST['text'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM myText WHERE text = '".$txt."'");
        $quantity = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
        echo $quantity->total;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I get these warnings:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.

Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given.

Comment: $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM myText WHERE text = '".$txt."'");

Comment: Your suggestion is good but please provide `bind statement` for preventing sql injection http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php